# The easiest way to go from HTML5 app to Android APK

Tags: android, html, cordova, mobile, apk

I've used Apache Cordova in the past, but I find it to be a headache. Spent a lot of time just to get it to compile correctly, almost more than developing the HTML5 app itself.

Is there some simple stand alone (offline) tool that takes a HTML5 project (HTML, CSS,JS, PNG, JPG files) and converts it to an APK with a simple press of a button?

Or is there some other way to piggy-back on some existing Android app, that just hosts a web browser, and then loads my HTML5 app?

Or is there a way to zip up the HTML5 project and distribute it as an app on an app store?

Or is there a way for the Android chrome browser to "appify" the current visited web page? The idea would be that the user presses a button to save down the current web page to the file system, and he can then access it offline as a regular app.

Comment: If you want to "appifify" your website like you describe in your last paragraph, look for tutorials on creating progressive web apps, that's exactly what they do

Comment: Thanks Patrick, sounds like exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Webview` to show html files inside Android App. You can also show a particular website by giving its link. More Details here.. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Yea, but then I have to install the Android SDK, JDK and all that stuff. Still too difficult.